# Is changing teams at this point bad for my career?

Tags: career-development

I work in a big tech company. I was promoted to be a people manager a year ago. It's the first time I manage people.

- With all the layoffs madness happening, some other managers got fired, so I ended up having to manage 16 people.
- I have to take care of a nine-digit number of users, which means very active work, a lot of internal/external stakeholders to manage.
- My team still does not have a product owner, so I have to put that hat too.

I learned a lot about delegation, creating processes, solving conflicts ... But also I am missing a lot of stuff, my backlog is pilling up, I am working 12 hours a day. I feel such a big team is a very big jump for someone who just started managing people. I am thinking of changing teams, which is now allowed.

My question is: I'm getting a lot of experience, but isn't it better for my career to work in a smaller team? and would that be seen as a escape from the problem?

Comment: What would happen if you stopped working 12 hours and worked normal hours?

Comment: Question: Where do you want your career to go? Because depending on your desired career trajectory, leaving will either be a nothing-burger, a boon or detrimental.

Comment: @nvoigt I started working normal hours recently. Also because I'm stressed. Nothing happened, my manager is aware of the situation, but still I'm not giving enough attention to my people's growth, product's vision, team's conflict ...

Comment: @TheDemonLord I want to continue in the management direction. I'm very motivated about that.

Comment: @Nfgbfvwiarswk - then I'd say if this is the direction you want to continue on, then learning how to handle a badly run business when everything is on fire will be good experience and make managing a properly run business seem like childs play.

Answer (score 7):

> I'm getting a lot of experience,

That's a really good thing

> but isn't it better for my career to work in a smaller team?

I don't think so, you are looking at the wrong solution

> and would that be seen as a escape from the problem?

Yes. You are not solving the problem, you are evading it.

A better question would be: **"How can I make this work?"**

First of all: your situation is not unusual for new managers. Take heart: larger teams can (and are) being managed quite well, you just have to do  figure the best way to do it in your case.

You are already off to a good start: you have identified the core problems. Next step is to think about potential solutions, make a preliminary plan and than discuss with your boss.

Some examples of potential solutions

> I ended up having to manage 16 people.

Too many and there is plenty of research to support it. Consider a different structure for the team: split into a few sub teams with their own manager, groom a few strong people to step in, etc.

> I have to take care of a nine-digit number of users, which means very active work, a lot of internal/external stakeholders to manage. ... my backlog is pilling up

You may have to take a hit on this front until the other two problems are solved. There shouldn't be any technical work on your backlog before the other stuff is sorted out. Delegate what you can.

> My team still does not have a product owner, so I have to put that hat too

A product owner needs to be hired or groomed.

Setup a 1:1 with your boss and present your problem statement and your plan. Communicate friendly but clearly that the current situation isn't long term sustainable so something needs to happen and that something may have to take priority over the day-to-day business for a while.

Discuss, brainstorm, adjust until you have a plan that you both feel is viable.  Define clear roles and responsibilities (including whatever your boss needs to do as well) and put some progress metrics or milestones in place and start executing. Check in frequently on progress and adjust as needed.

Don't be afraid to lean on your boss there: that IS their job the same way as yours is to support your team.

Your career will benefit quite a bit, if this works out: A) you have demonstrated that you can lead a sizable team. B) You have shown that you can solve fairly complicated organizational problems. C) Your work is going to be a lot more fun, less stress and you'll built significant confidence yourself and in others.

Answer (score 1):

Suddenly becoming responsible for the output of 10 other people (or 16) is no easy task.

There are two important questions:

1. Do you want to grow as a people manager, or as an expert contributor? There's also options in between, like project managers and architects (with managing functions).
2. How well are you doing? Ask your superiors and others at your level for an honest evaluation.

If you want to eventually manage more and more people, this experience, however hard it is, and even if it's a failure, will prepare you for the challenges ahead. Like the cycling saying, *"it never gets easier, you just go faster"*.

Managing large teams is a skill, not something intuitive and automatic. It takes training or education, practice, mentorship, feedback to do it well. In practice most people start out without any of that, though, which tends to lowers the expectations.

So see how you compare to the expectations. If you aren't doing well, and are pushing above your weight, this increases your chances of burning out or subtly failing some of your duties, resulting in losses in either job or personal life.

If both are good - you want to manage and your results are above average - take extra time learning, either from courses or from your colleagues, to make this role go smoother.

If you aren't sure if it's your thing, it may make sense to consider a smaller team, where you will learn at a more practical pace than "thrown in the deep end". Be very honest about everything, including your workload, but also your professional desires and intentions. Expert careers in big tech often pay as much as management ones. And there are middle grounds, like the technical program manager route, which put less emphasis on day-to-day people management.

Finally, if it's mixed... then it's a difficult decision, but still, comes down to what you want in the end.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting a lot of experience, but isn't it better for my career to
> work in a smaller team? and would that be seen as a escape from the
> problem?

Getting a lot of experience is generally a good thing for your career.

It sounds as if your motivation is to get an easier role. If it comes across that way within your company, that might not be good. You don't want to inadvertently signal that you aren't up to the challenge.

Tough call. Only you have enough information to make this decision. If you have a mentor in the company, or a close colleague, perhaps talk it over with them.